# Problems with wine

Tags: command-line, wine

I don't know why but I am getting these errors automatically as mentioned in the screenshot. I tried a lot but still can't solve it!

Help would be much appreciated!

error #1:

[image: error #1]

error #2:

[image: error #2]

Comment: You've not provided the basic details as to what Ubuntu product & release you're using, as well as architecture (*which can lead to problems with `wine`*).  Please also copy & paste text into your question & not pictures; we can't easily copy/paste from a picture to explore possible causes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please dont use images for text information

Answer (score 2):

The error messages mean that your version of Wine does not support all the syscalls that your application is requesting. You cannot use that version of Wine with that application. There is no workaround -- in all the FIXME cases, the code simply did not exist for that release of Wine.

You can test a newer version of Wine, but that requires a newer release of Ubuntu (New Wine + Old Ubuntu = Broken System). You can use a 23.10 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment or a Virtual Machine to protect your system while you test.

The Wine Project does not promise 100% Windows compatibility. They have limited resources for a monumental task: They are trying to reverse-engineer decades of Windows source code that they have never seen.

Be sure to report your testing results to WineHQ. They cannot work on it if nobody tells them about it. If you have Windows development experience, the Wine developers would love your help.

In the meanwhile, consider running your application in a Virtual Machine instead of Wine.